# "WHERE" clause in Firebase client

Tags: c#, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Im new to Firebase, currently have a Real time firebase database, im trying to add a "WHERE" clause to the code that returns data. I need to return all rows that have UserId = userId.

I have tried -

```
firebaseClient.Child("MapPins/UserId/" + userId)
```

and

```
firebaseClient.Child("MapPins")
.Child("UserId")
.Child(userId)
```

The code below currently returns all pins, regardless of the userid field.

```
public async Task<ObservableCollection<MapPinModel>> GetPinsForUserFirebase(string userId)
{
    ObservableCollection<MapPinModel> mapView = new ObservableCollection<MapPinModel>();

    try
    {
        var collection = firebaseClient.Child("MapPins")                    
        .AsObservable<MapPinModel>()
        
        .Subscribe((dbevent) =>
        {
            
            if (dbevent.Object != null)
            {
                mapView.Add(dbevent.Object);
            }
        });
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
    return mapView;
}
```

Here is the data structure

[image: Screenshot of the structure]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to be certain without seeing your data structure, but I think you're looking for:

```
firebaseClient.Child("MapPins")
  .OrderBy("UserId")
  .EqualTo(userId)
  ...
```

Comment: .OrderByChild isn't recognised. Ill update the post with the data structure

Comment: If you're using this library https://github.com/step-up-labs/firebase-database-dotnet, it is called `OrderBy("UserId")`. Honestly, auto-complete should be your friend here.